# Elements doesn't get affected by imported stylesheet despite it showing up under sources in the console

Tags: html, import, console, sass

In my project I have a `style.scss` file where I import another css file called `login.scss`, using `@import "login";`. Then when I go to my browser I can see that the elements affected by the `login.scss` file doesn't get their rules.

This seems odd to me since when I look under "sources" in the console and go to `style.css` I can see that the `style.scss` file does indeed contain the rules as intended for the login elements. When I inspect the elements however they are just blank of any rules except for the default ones..

Here you can see that the `import` of the `login.scss` file is working:

[image: style.css]

But if you take a look here the elements have no rules:

[image: form's rules]

I have **not** included

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/login.css">
```

in the head section since I shouldn't have to do that when using `import` in the main file.. Right?

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in the HTML where an element was placed outside of another element, thus causing the entire CSS to fail because the selectors would be in the wrong order.